# how to add template parameter to global function?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I'm working with some legacy code, and trying to get it to compile in Linux. It was originally built in visual studio, whose compiler didn't keep with standards. Anyways, now I'm going through the code fixing it and I came across a templated function that is declared globally. I get the error:

> /home/blah/blah;/blah.h:78:
>   error: there are no arguments to
>   ‘Clip’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘Clip’
>   must be available

I have been able to fix this same error before when they were in a specific scope by doing myClass::Clip. However, since it has no scope, how do I resolve this?

Updated: here's the declaration of the Clip function:

```
template<class T> inline T Clip( T x, T bot, T top )
{ return(( x>=bot && x<=top ) ? x : (( x<bot ) ? bot : top )); }
```

The call to Clip:

```
src_row = Clip( dst_row + h, 0, SR ); 
//dst_row + h, 0, SR are all int's... does that help?
//btw, love the quick responses, thanks.
```

The call and the declaration are in different '.h' files

Comment: Can you post the declaration for the `Clip` Function?

Comment: And also please post the code that generates the error message, and the error mesasge that it generates.

Comment: Getting closer. What are `dst_row`, `h`, and `SR`?

Comment: Just a note: the common name for this function is `clamp`, not `clip`. It's better to stick with common terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a declaration of `Clip` somewhere before the template definition that caused this error.  If `Clip` itself is not a template, an ordinary declaration will do.  If `Clip` is a function template and you find the definition of `Clip`, you can usually just copy the start of that definition and replace the `{...}` with a `;` to get a valid declaration.

Edit:  Okay, so you've found the definition of `Clip`, let's say in clip.h.  And your compile error is in problem.h.

The best thing to do is probably to add `#include <clip.h>` near the top of problem.h.  Make sure both have guards against multiple #includes.

But that might not work if it introduces a circular header dependency.  If adding the `#include` causes different errors, you can try just putting the declaration (not definition) of `Clip` in problem.h before the definition that gave the error.  This would be the part where you just copy and paste and replace `{...}` with `;`.

```
template<class T> inline T Clip( T x, T bot, T top );
```

Comment: Wow, this is, um, embarrassing... :). I thought I had tried it, but I just needed to include the .h file that has the declaration. This confuses me though, why did this make a difference? The compiler found the function's declaration before I added the .h file (... or did it?). Thanks.

Comment: The compiler error you quoted is essentially saying "Clip looks like a function, but I haven't seen any declaration for it."  But it's worded the way it is because in a template definition, there are some exceptions to the rule about needing a declaration before a use, and it's trying to explain that this does not count as one of those exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix this problem using the scope reoslution operator.  Like this:

```
::Clip<params>(...);
```

But its hard to tell exactly what problem you're having.  please post code & exact error mesasges.